# How to "bump" a question that's the same as the one you wanted to ask

Tags: discussion, etiquette, old-questions, bump

I wanted to ask a question about Hibernate and polymorphism, and before asking it I searched on Google, and lo and behold, there was already [a question on SO about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979200/hibernate-polymorphism). It's three weeks old and has never really been answered. What's the most appropriate way to "bump" it up to being higher up in the "active" list? I don't have an answer to it myself, and I'm not the OP so I don't want to edit the original post. And SO etiquette says I shouldn't ask a duplicate question. What should I do?

Comment: Agreed, take a look at the question linked by @ChrisF, there is a good discussion(Meta) starting there, surrounding this issue.

Comment: All three - this one (1471), 1409 and 1124 all address the same problem from slightly different angles. 1124 is about bumping your own question whereas 1409 and this one are about bumping someone else's

Comment: Yeah, they're all very similar, but 3rd-party bounties don't exist now, and it's not my question.

Comment: I'm just looking for feedback to do something appropriate that won't be frowned upon.

Comment: (And then, what do you do if you're a low-rep person in this situation? I don't have to worry about that myself, but I can see the situation coming up.)

Comment: Doesn't a comment also bump the question? Can easily be removed afterwords...

Comment: Checked it... Apparently it doesn't :-s

Comment: gotta love how older questions get marked as duplicates of newer ones

Comment: Not a dupe. Vote to reopen!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Edit the question and make it better - even if you just go through and fix a few typos, improve formatting a little, or make the title more descriptive.

I don't like the idea of doing a "null edit" where nothing really changes, or editing a tag for the sake of editing a tag.

A better question is more likely to be answered, so spending a bit of time improving it (less than if you had to write the question from scratch) is to every-ones benefit!

Comment: I agree if it has obvious typos / tag or title problems. Otherwise I keep my hands off other people's questions....

Comment: I think this is the most "polite" way of bumping a question, most people won't mind if you fix a trivial typo or two, especially compared to adding invisible HTML comments

Comment: And what if you don't have enough reputation to edit the question?

Comment: But improving or fixing the answer is not always feasible. For example, someone may have asked a question that is somewhat specific to them, and someone else may have the same basic question, but specific to themselves. At best, it would be awkward to step in and modify someone else’s question. For example, Whaid [asked this](http://superuser.com/questions/171333/how-to-reinstall-the-host-only-network-adapter-in-vmware-7). It uses thinks like *I did this* and *I have that*. I too need to figure out a way to reinstall VMWare NICs on the host, but would feel pushy if I just edit his question.

Answer (score -2):

I guess *technically* you could change a tag, then change it back to what it was. I don't think editing tags puts the question in danger of morphing to community wiki (I think just edits to the main body do that). Not sure if this would be "appropriate" etiquette, though.

Answer (score -5):

What I do is add something like this to the question (usually my own though):

```
<!-- Shameless bump -->
```

That way the question gets bumped but doesn't change.

Comment: Yes, but that does put the question "in danger of morphing to communitiy wiki" like gnovice has worded so well...

Comment: @fretje - That, and it is smelly.

Comment: Yeah, that's why i only do it to my own questions.