# What's the ranking algorithm of SO?

Tags: discussion, rankings

Will editing the question make it rank forward or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing the question will rank it forward, being the newest until of course another one gets asked, answered or bumped, unless the question has a reputation of -5 or less. The order in the Recent QUestions/Active tab is by last activity date. Votes do not count towards that activity, neither does flaging or voting to close, or commenting.

Have a look at these questions about [bumping questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4397/purposeful-question-bumping-abuse-or-feature) and [getting attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions) and the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) towards the bottom.

Comment: To make it further,will it become the newest after editing?

Comment: I mean,rank first by date

Comment: Editing a post will not move it to the top of the Newest Questions list, only to the Active list.

Answer (score 0):

From the [FAQs](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) :

> **What if I don't get a good answer?**
>
> In order to get good answers, you have
>   to put some effort into the question.
>   Edit your question to provide status
>   and progress updates. Document your
>   own continued efforts to answer your
>   question. This will naturally bump
>   your question and get more people
>   interested in it.
>
> If, after two days, you still don't
>   have an answer you like, you can offer
>   a bounty. Slice off a bit of your own
>   hard-earned reputation -- anywhere
>   from 50 to 500 -- and attach it to the
>   question as a bounty. We'll even throw
>   in 50 reputation to sweeten the deal.
>   The bountied question will appear with
>   a special icon in all question lists,
>   and it will also be visible on the
>   home page Featured tab.
>
> Once initiated, the bounty period
>   lasts seven days. If you mark an
>   accepted answer, your bounty is
>   awarded to the answerer (do note that
>   accepted bounty answers are permanent
>   and cannot be changed). If you do not
>   accept an answer in seven days, the
>   top voted answer will automatically
>   become the accepted answer, and half
>   your bounty will be awarded to that
>   answer. You will always give up the
>   amount of reputation specified in the
>   bounty, so if you start a bounty, be
>   sure to follow up and accept the best
>   answer!
>
> Of course, bounty awards, like all
>   accepted answers, are immune to the
>   daily reputation cap and community
>   wiki mode.