# How many down votes does it take on meta for a question to stop from being bumped?

Tags: support, down-votes, bump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many downvotes to push an active question off the “active” list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117119/how-many-downvotes-to-push-an-active-question-off-the-active-list)

The ranking mechanism is different from the main sites, but how different?

On main [it seems to take -5 votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18409/157047) for a question to stop from being bumped, how much is it on meta?

Comment: Let's find out! :D

Comment: Questions with a score of -8 will not appear on the active tab, but they'll still be bumped as they are updated on the general Questions view (or at least, it's my *understanding* that they will). Is that what you mean?

Comment: When I alluded to this previously, I was talking about [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62729/meta-sites-front-pages-should-not-hide-questions-with-very-low-scores/62769#62769), slightly different from the "bump" requirement perhaps. I thought edited questions were "bumped" to the homepage regardless of their score.

Comment: Thanks guys! I wanted to link to it in a discussion, couldn't find it immediately.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Thank you, that's highly relevant extra info. I always have the 'active' tab on by default it seems. I'm guessing it _is_ default?

Comment: @CodyGray It might be more constructive linking me to it directly next time? Just a thought. ;p