# How to deal with question bumping

Tags: discussion, bump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Purposeful Question Bumping: Abuse or feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4397/purposeful-question-bumping-abuse-or-feature)

[What concept is used in .net for creating mobile software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199401/what-concept-used-in-net-for-creating-mobile-software)

so the edit history is obviously a bunch of phony edits intended to bump the question..

I feel this isn't "proper" behavior, but what is the best way to deal with the situation?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4397/purposeful-question-bumping-abuse-or-feature

Comment: Flag it as spam and/or mod attention.

Comment: "Phony"? What are you talking about? Can't you appreciate the deep moral dilemma this guy was in, trying to decide if his sentence should end with seven, five, two, one or no dots?

Comment: They.. must be.. channel...ing their... inner... Shatner. @bal

Comment: I didn't know edits bumped a question...is that making it rank higher in activity, thus more noticeable? I'll have to watch my edits then...  :S

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123105/how-to-learn-flex/2123140#2123140
44 revisions...

Answer (score 4):

The best way to deal with this is to flag the post for moderator attention, with a short note describing what you've observed. The moderators will take care of it from there.

Answer (score 3):

No matter what moderators can do, why not just leave a public comment? Then everyone who reads it might learn about it. These sites are [run by us](https://stackoverflow.com/about), right?

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually surprised the question has gone that long without someone rewriting it.

In any case, see [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4397/purposeful-question-bumping-abuse-or-feature). Trivial edits in order to bump a question are perfectly acceptable, if it is getting out hand, then just flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: the emphasis there was "Just make sure your edit improves the question in some measurable way." I'm just asking about protocol when it doesn't. Like, it doesn't make sense to "vote to close" -- it's still a real question -- but non-moderators can't "vote to lock"

Comment: You're right, but like I said, you can flag it and have a moderator lock it if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to vote to close as "spam". That usually hasn't any effect (only in the rarest of cases such a question will get to five close votes), so it's more a symbolic gesture.

Comment: ...but the question asker will remain totally oblivious, unless (s)he has 3k+ reputation and can see the vote count?

Comment: @Arjan: I assume the question asker needs only 250 reputation to see the votes (rep limit for closing your own questions)

Comment: I think you're right.  I can see close votes on my own questions on meta, and I have 501 rep at the time of writing this

Answer (score 0):

1. It would only make sense if you have a good question or answer that is likely to get upvoted. Otherwise, there are easier ways to get reputation.
2. The user can edit all s/he wants, the post was made a CW. In fact, all of the user's top question were made CW in the same way.