# Bumping questions

Tags: support, questions, bump

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Purposeful Question Bumping: Abuse or feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4397/purposeful-question-bumping-abuse-or-feature)
>   [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

I'm wondering whether it's possible to bump an unanswered question?

Comment: Related question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4397/purposeful-question-bumping-abuse-or-feature

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions