# Ability to "bump" a question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please add a way to ‘bump’ questions back to the front page.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/please-add-a-way-to-bump-questions-back-to-the-front-page)

How about a bump feature along with the bounty? Some [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45476/negative-daily-reputation-display) aren't applicable for a bounty as it would most likely expire with no net gain other then rep loss.

Would a question "bump this question" costing 1 rep (or 2, 3, whatever) be applicable? Of course you would only make this attainable at a certain rep level (150?) and you could either limit it to your own questions or allow anyone to bump anyone else's question.

Comment: -1 for bumping your own questions +1 for bumping other's questions

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4397/purposeful-question-bumping-abuse-or-feature about bumping. We can already accomplish bumping by editing. There is no real other necessary measure in my opinion

Comment: Yes, but then you have to find a good reason to edit the darn question. Sometimes (See some of my SO questions) there is only so much you can edit in. It's not about rep whoring or getting views, it's about **wanting an answer**. Fundamentally I believe this is a necessary feature of the SO machine because it enables this primary role to be fulfilled.

Comment: What makes an unedited answer more appealing than one that has been edited, however minor that edit? If it happens too frequently people will flag it all the same. If the question isn't interesting enough to get the right people to answer it, how is *not changing it* going to help it get answered?

Comment: It's not *is the question interesting enough*, it's *how fast is it getting bumped off of the front page*.