# Links to the Wayback Machine are broken in chat transcript

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, hyperlinks, chat-transcript

[This chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19527372#19527372) is an example of the bug. It looks like this in regular chat:

[image: "Here's the essay: Tropes, Facts and Empiricism by Daryn Lehoux"]

That link points to:

```
http://web.archive.org/web/20080409050311/http://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/daryn.lehoux/Tropes.pdf
```

In the transcript, it looks like this:

[image: "Here's the essay: {a plaintext URL with some broken HTML} Tropes, Facts and Empiricism by Daryn Lehoux"]

That link points to:

```
http://web.archive.org/web/20080409050311/%3Ca%20href=
```

... which doesn't work so well! Could this be fixed? I'm not sure if this impacts links to elsewhere.

Comment: Looks like the double `http://` is the culprit, not sure it's a valid URL. If it's invalid URL I'd say this is by design, and the bug in in the web archive site itself generating invalid links. (Which might be working only due to merciful browsers not enforcing URL rules)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: the URL is kind-off valid; colons are reserved characters and should be represented by %3A instead, but in practice browsers just support the unescaped colon *in the path section* of a URL. Which is why regular chat supports Wayback Engine urls, and the transcript should just be fixed.

Comment: It would be good to get some come-back on this. Wayback Machine links are often used to fix link-rot, and if they are rendered "in-chat" correctly, it is passing strange that they are rendered "in-transcript" **in**correctly.

Comment: @Davïd You have more than enough rep to place a bounty, rather than pointless edits to bump a question. It also wouldn't be so bad if you had 2k and not shoved this into the review queue. You are essentially asking reviewers to authorise a bump, not a useful edit. See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4409/230506 :)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, @James - bounty never occurred to me (obviously), but could do, I suppose. And I *am* a <2K user here, so edits (ok, not the most meaningful, but I think it *is* "better"!) were my recourse. Will know better next time!

Comment: The bug is still there.

Comment: [Starboards are affected too](http://i.imgur.com/vhtrXXu.png).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm not sure if this impacts links to elsewhere.

Yeah, it does. In fact this bug could be used to exploit an XSS vulnerability :(

Thanks to [Gothdo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3853934/gothdo) for responsibly disclosing the vulnerability to us, and thanks to [ArtOfCode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/262823/artofcode) for putting a bounty on this question – I wouldn't be surprised if the bounty was what made Gothdo aware of the issue :)

And of course thanks to you for writing this in the first place.

It's fixed now.

Comment: Also thanks to [Ferrybig](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1542723/ferrybig) for helping to work the bug out with Gothdo.

Comment: I made Gothdo aware of it because he passed by while I was trying to exploid it... https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111569/xss-test

Comment: *Note to self: to have a bug fixed, find how it can be exploited...*

Comment: There were 2 bounties... :( Anyway, great to see it fixed, especially knowing it was a vulnerability. Cheers Balpha.