# What is the best way to bump/re-ask an old question?

Tags: support, questions, new-users, bump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to “bump” a question that's the same as the one you wanted to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1471/how-to-bump-a-question-thats-the-same-as-the-one-you-wanted-to-ask)
>   [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

I want to ask a question on Stackoverflow, but I found the exact question had already been asked.  This would be good, but the question is now 20 months old.  The answers are likely to have changed in that time so I'd like to make the question more visible again to get a better result.  What is the best way to do this?  I could ask the same question again.  I'd really like to be able to bump the question but I don't see a way of doing that.

The question is:
[What is your favorite Python mocking library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98053/what-is-your-favorite-python-mocking-library)

Answer (score 4):

If you edit the question or add a new answer it will get bumped.  If you know of a mocking library that's not mentioned already (maybe one that's been released in the past 20 months), I'd suggest adding it as an answer.

If your goal is to get other people to add new answers, then I'd also suggest you wait until peak traffic sometime tomorrow to bump the question.